migration from centos 7 to Ubuntu 22.04 MYSQL High Memory and not getting released
migration from centos 7 to Ubuntu 22.04 MYSQL High Memory and not getting released
free see slowly buffer getting zero

free -h
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          172Gi        55Gi       1.6Gi       3.0Mi       116Gi       116Gi
Swap:          23Gi        50Mi        23Gi
pamadmin@chnoptvpslavdb02:~$

buffer is not getting released
